# Swift protocol for UIViewController subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Is it possible to declare a protocol and also define the type of object that can conform to it?

I have a set of closures that I'd like to configure in various different subclasses of `UIViewController` in my project. (They are all related).

I'd like to have a factory function that creates the correct type of `UIViewController` subclass but then returns it as a protocol type.

That way I can then configure the various closures and push the view controller onto the navigation controller.

I can either...

Return the `UIViewController` superclass and push it onto the navigation stack but then not be able to set the closures properly as the compiler doesn't know it conforms to the protocol.

or...

Return the protocol type and I'm able to set the closures properly but then the compiler doesn't know that it's a `UIViewController` subclass so I can't push it onto the navigation controller.

Is there a way to do both?

Thanks

Comment: You can determine at runtime whether an object conforms to a protocol

Comment: @NazmulHasan Ah, so you're saying just return them as `UIViewController` and then do an `if let...` to determine that it conforms to the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective C you were able to declare a variable like this:

```
UIViewController <Protocol> *variable;
```

Unfortunately, this is not possible with Swift, which considering how protocol-oriented Swift is, it's very strange.

This is pretty uncomfortable because like you found out, the compiler can't be aware of both the class and the protocol at the same time, so you have to cast twice, you have to check that the object is of the allowed class at runtime, and have to document it in your code to prevent people from sending the wrong kind of object.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Pity it seems I'm not able to do it. I can do like Nazmul commented in the question but then you could either pass a UIViewController that doesn't conform to the protocol or a different type of object that does. Have to code defensively for it either way. Thanks for confirming though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!
Do it like this..

```
// a protocol to make sure the the conforming object is subclass of UIViewController

public protocol IamViewController { }

//make every UIViewController  adopt the IamViewController protocol

extension UIViewController:IamViewController { }

//create your protocol and add a requirement that it must be UIViewController if it want to conform to it

protocol vcObject:IamViewController{ }
```

Comment: Ah ok. I like this. The IAmViewController protocol is purely there to "tag" every ViewController so the compiler can recognise it. Nice, will have a look tomorrow when I'm back at work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are correct, this is how I did it, in my project.