# Can I declare a type that is a specific class conforming to a protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift

If I have the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    ...
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to declare a type that accepts a class or subclass of `MyClass` conforming to `MyProtocol`?

e.g. in pseudo code:

```
var thing: MyClass & MyProtocol = ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift protocol for UIViewController subclasses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596262/swift-protocol-for-uiviewcontroller-subclasses)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Check this question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596262/swift-protocol-for-uiviewcontroller-subclasses/39596523#comment66501660_39596523

Comment: Your english sentence says `or` but your code says `&` (and). Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach works (i.e. specify the type first and then use it in the variable declaration):

```
class MCImplementingMP: MyClass, MyProtocol {   
}

var thing: MCImplementingMP = ...
```

Comment: No, it's not working. What if you want to assign to `thing` something that is instance of `MyClass`, conforms to `MyProtocol` but _is not_ instance of `MCImplementingMP`?

Comment: The question would be **why** it's not such an instance...other than as an academic exercise.  If someone's designing a code base with a selection of "My..." types, using the type that provides a correct match isn't difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it was possible in Objective-C but not possible in Swift. 
All solutions that I know looks like hacks and require lot of runtime type checking. So I came out with my own - declare a wrapper type which can act like needed class or protocol depending on circumstances:

```
class MyClass {}
protocol MyProtocol: class {}

class Wrapper {
    var instance: AnyObject
    init?(instance: MyClass) {
        guard instance is MyProtocol else { return nil }
        self.instance = instance
    }

    init?(instance: MyProtocol) {
        guard instance is MyClass else { return nil }
        self.instance = instance
    }

    var instanceAsMyClass: MyClass {
        return instance as! MyClass
    }

    var instanceAsMyProtocol: MyProtocol {
        return instance as! MyProtocol
    }
}
```

You may want to change property names but idea is clear.